# Apache Commons Lang Exception

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am trying to use **StringUtil class** from Apache Commons Lang jar **(commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip)**.
So I added this jar to my class path and I ran that program.
When I ran my code I am getting an exception like
`"Caused by:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"`.

I opened this class using java decompiler and when I opened its showing as
`"// INTERNAL ERROR //"`. Except this class all other classes are fine.

After that I downloaded the source code and I compile that class and I opened that compiled class in java decompiler then it also shows the same error. So how can I solve this issue and how can I use this issue[image]

Answer (score 1):

Between commons-lang 2.x.x and 3.x.x the packages have move from `org.apache.commons.lang` (that is missing to your code according to the exception) to `org.apache.commons.lang3` as presented in your screenshot.

Either you downgrade to commons-lang 2.6 or you update your code to change the import declaration from `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` to `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`

Comment: Actually I am using this library for as a supportive jar. I am trying to use Apache CXF to extract the classes from wsdl bt its internally using this StringUtils Class. So its not under control of mine. I am already using some of the classes from "Apache commons lang3" but not StringUtils. So if use both the versions in my project it will create another problems. So is the issue with Apache ...?

Comment: Since they are in distinct packages, this should not create problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you downloaded is right.

Make sure the jar you added to your project isn't **commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip**, but is **commons-lang3-3.1.jar** in commons-lang3-3.1-bin.zip.

Comment: Hay I am using Jar only not the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

> http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html
>
> Java code Despite the label of backwards incompatibility, in the vast
>   majority of cases the simple addition of a '3' to an import statement
>   will suffice for your migration.
>
> Change: import org.apache.commons.lang -> import
>   org.apache.commons.lang3

Comment: Actually I am using this library for as a supportive jar. I am trying to use Apache CXF to extract the classes from wsdl bt its internally using this StringUtils Class. So its not under control of mine. I am already using some of the classes from "Apache commons lang3" but not StringUtils. So if use both the versions in my project it will create another problems. So is the issue with Apache ...?

Comment: "So if use both the versions in my project it will create another problems" what's problem?